# How to construct a string for a Unix system() call from C program

Tags: c, unix, command

I'm trying to make my C program run a command in Unix using `system()`.

Can I make something like `system("stat myFile")`, where `myFile` is a variable in my program?
Is there any other way possible?

Answer (score 1):

`system()` takes a pointer-to-char or a char array. You can construct it as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char command[256]; /* Big enough for "stat " + longest file name. */
char *myFile = "/my/file";
/* ... */
sprintf (command, "stat %s", myFile);
system(commmand);
```

This should get you going, but note that a hard limit like 256 is not bullet-proof coding due to a possible buffer overrun if `myFile` is a looooong name. Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious file names are not unheard of :-) If you want to do it like a pro, the next step would be to read the `snprintf` manual and ask your shell for
`getconf _POSIX_PATH_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: **don't**. `system` has lots of problems you don't want to deal with:

1. It runs the external program via the shell, so you have to worry about properly escaping any filenames or other options you pass when building your string. Failure to do so could create dangerous bugs.
2. `system` suspends your program until the program you run finishes.
3. There's no way to read back the output from the program you run via `system`.

Using `popen` solves all of the problems except shell escaping and is very convenient. Using `fork` and `execvp`, or `posix_spawnp`, is more complex but solves all of the above problems and more.

Answer (score 0):

For that particular case of running [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) command, you could use instead the [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) syscall instead. See [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Hence use

```
  struct stat mys;
  memset (&mys, 0, sizeof(mys));
  if (stat(filename, &mys)) { perror(filename); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  /// use mys
```

In general you might consider using [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) or [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) to build a command string, and using [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) or [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) to run it. This is not advisable if you can avoid that (possibility of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection), so you need to consider shell escapes, etc...).

You should also read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), perhaps to know about [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) etc...